# Mostrar información adicional dentro de un option de Datalist

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Estoy a través de una AJAX mostrando información de los productos (precios, stock, referencia ,s tock, etc.), de acuerdo al punto de venta y los agrego a una tabla html:

```
$(document).on('click', '#agregar_linea', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var bodega = $('#bodega').val(),
        id_bodega = $('#lista_bodega' + ' [value="' + bodega + '"]').data('id');
    if (bodega == '') {//Se valida que se haya ingresado el punto de venta
        $('#bodega').focus();
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'AVISO',
                text: 'Debe seleccionar el punto de venta para mostrar las referencias',
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 2000
            });
        } else if (bodega != '' && id_bodega == undefined) {
            $('#bodega').focus();
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'AVISO',
                text: 'La bodega seleccionada es inválida',
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 2000
            });
        } else {
            var contenido_fila = '';
            dataString = 'val=1' + '&canal=' + canal + '&id_bodega=' + id_bodega + '&grupo=' + grupo;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "orden_pedido_items.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(data) {
                if (data.val == 0) {
                    contenido_fila = data.contets;
                    var fila_nueva = $('<tr class="tr" id="fila_item[]" name="fila_item[]">');
                    fila_nueva.append(contenido_fila);
                    $("#table_ref tbody").append(fila_nueva);
                    $('input[name="referencia[]"]').focus();
                    reorder();
                } else {
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'error',
                        title: 'AVISO',
                        text: 'No se encontraron referencias con unidades disponibles en la bodega seleccionada: ' + bodega,
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        timer: 2000
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Archivo PHP:

```
if ( $val == 1 ) {//Se inicia código para listar las referencias de la bodega seleccionada
    $grupo = $_POST["grupo"];//Se captura el grupo del usuario
    //Query para listar los articulos de acuerdo a la bodega seleccionada
    if ($grupo==5){//Si el creador es del área técnica, sólo se visualizarán los repuestos
        $bodega = $link->query('SELECT * FROM articulo WHERE ARTICULO_BODEGA = '.$id_bodega.' AND ARTICULO_ESTADO = 1 AND ARTICULO_ARTICULO_VISIBILIDAD_CANAL_ID='.$canal.' AND ARTICULO_CANTIDAD>0 AND ARTICULO_CATEGORIA IN(1,2,12,20) ORDER BY ARTICULO_REFERENCIA');
    }else{
        $bodega = $link->query('SELECT * FROM articulo WHERE ARTICULO_BODEGA = '.$id_bodega.' AND ARTICULO_ESTADO = 1 AND ARTICULO_ARTICULO_VISIBILIDAD_CANAL_ID='.$canal.' AND ARTICULO_CANTIDAD>0 AND (ARTICULO_CATEGORIA NOT IN(1,2,12,20) OR TIPO_COMPONENTE_ID=2) ORDER BY ARTICULO_REFERENCIA');
    }
    if ($bodega->num_rows > 0) {//Se valida si encontró registros del query realizado
        $data['val'].=0;
        $data['contets'].='<td width="15px"></td>';
        $data['contets'].='<td width="150px">';
            $data['contets'].='<input type="text" list="lista_ref" id="referencia[]" name="referencia[]" size="25" placeholder="Referencia del artículo">';
            $data['contets'].='<datalist id="lista_ref" name="lista_ref[]">';
                while ($rowRef = $bodega->fetch_assoc()){//Se recorre el resultado del query
                    $desc_producto = $rowRef["ARTICULO_NOMBRE"];//Descripción del artículo
                    $articulo_defectuoso = $rowRef["ARTICULO_DEFECTUOSA"];//Cantidad del artículo en inventario con defectos
                    $articulo_incompleto = $rowRef["ARTICULO_INCOMPLETA"];//Cantidad del artículo en inventario que están incompletos. Normalmente, se dan en papeles
                    if ($articulo_defectuoso==0 && $articulo_incompleto==0){//Todas las cantidades en stock son nuevos o están en buen estado
                        $articulo_nuevo = $rowRef["ARTICULO_CANTIDAD"];//Stock actual de la referencia
                    }else if ($articulo_defectuoso>0 && $articulo_incompleto==0){//Del stock, hay algunas defectuosos
                        $articulo_nuevo = (int)$rowRef["ARTICULO_CANTIDAD"]-(int)$articulo_defectuoso;
                    }else if ($articulo_defectuoso>0 && $articulo_incompleto>0){//Del stock hay algunas defectuosas e incompletas
                        $articulo_nuevo = (int)$rowRef["ARTICULO_CANTIDAD"]-((int)$articulo_defectuoso+(int)$articulo_incompleto);
                    }else if ($articulo_defectuoso==0 && $articulo_incompleto>0){//Del stock, hay algunas incompletas
                        $articulo_nuevo = (int)$rowRef["ARTICULO_CANTIDAD"]-(int)$articulo_incompleto;
                    }
                    $data['contets'].='<option value="'.$rowRef["ARTICULO_REFERENCIA"].' / '.$desc_producto.'" data-id="'.$rowRef["ARTICULO_ID"].'" data-cat="'.$rowRef["ARTICULO_CATEGORIA"].'" data-desc="'.$desc_producto.'" data-cant="'.$rowRef['ARTICULO_CANTIDAD'].'" data-precio="'.$rowRef['ARTICULO_PRECIO_VENTA'].'">Cant. Nuevas: '.$articulo_nuevo.', Cant. Defectuosos: '.$articulo_defectuoso.', Cant. Incompletas: '.$articulo_incompleto.'</option>';
                }
            $data['contets'].='</datalist>';
        $data['contets'].='<input type="hidden" name="id_referencia[]" id="id_referencia[]"></td>';
        $data['contets'].='<td width="200px"><input type="text" id="descripcion[]" name="descripcion[]" size="50" placeholder="Descripción del artículo" readOnly></td>';
        $data['contets'].='<td width="50px" align="center" valign="middle"><input type="text" id="cantidad[]" name="cantidad[]" size="2" onKeyPress="return onlyNumbers(event);" style="text-align: right;">';
        $data['contets'].='<input type="hidden" name="stock[]" id="stock[]"></td>';
        $data['contets'].='<td width="50px" align="center" valign="middle"><input type="text" id="precio[]" name="precio[]" size="10" onKeyPress="return onlyNumbers(event);" style="text-align: right;"></td>';
        $data['contets'].='<td width="50px" align="center" valign="middle"><input type="text" id="descuento_porcentaje[]" name="descuento_porcentaje[]" size="2" onKeyPress="return onlyNumbers(event);" style="text-align: right;"></td>';
        $data['contets'].='<td width="50px" align="center" valign="middle"><input type="text" id="descuento_valor[]" name="descuento_valor[]" size="10" onKeyPress="return onlyNumbers(event);" style="text-align: right;" readOnly></td>';
        $data['contets'].='<td width="50px" align="center" valign="middle"><input type="text" id="precio_total[]" name="precio_total[]" size="10" style="text-align: right;" readOnly></td>';
        $data['contets'].='<td width="18px" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="#" class="adelete hint--left hint--rounded" aria-label="Eliminar fila" style="text-decoration:none; color: #444;"><i class="icon-trash-o"></i></a></td>';
    }else{
        $data['val'].=1;
    }
}
```

Dentro de las opciones del datalist debo mostrar información adicional. Hay unos campos que indica que el producto está defectuoso, incompleto o es nuevo. Se me ocurrió colocar

```
$data['contets'].='<option value="'.$rowRef["ARTICULO_REFERENCIA"].'" data-id="'.$rowRef["ARTICULO_ID"].'" data-cat="'.$rowRef["ARTICULO_CATEGORIA"].'" data-desc="'.$desc_producto.'" data-cant="'.$rowRef['ARTICULO_CANTIDAD'].'" data-precio="'.$rowRef['ARTICULO_PRECIO_VENTA'].'"> '.$desc_producto.'Cant. Nuevas: '.$articulo_nuevo.', Cant. Defectuosos: '.$articulo_defectuoso.', Cant. Incompletas: '.$articulo_incompleto.'</option>';
```

Pero la información no me la muestra completa, pero la muestra no se muestra completa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego, se me ocurrió agregar saltos de líneas con "
" y "\n", pero no funcionó. Después de validar e investigar, concluí que no se puede agregar saltos de línea dentro de un option.

Encontré  que podía agregar toltip, lo intenté de dos maneras pero no me funcionaron

Con bootstrap:

```
<option value="<?php echo $rowRef["ARTICULO_REFERENCIA"]; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $rowRef["ARTICULO_ID"]; ?>" data-cat="<?php echo $rowRef["ARTICULO_CATEGORIA"]; ?>" data-desc="<?php echo $desc_producto; ?>" data-cant="<?php echo $rowRef['ARTICULO_CANTIDAD']; ?>" data-precio="<?php echo $rowRef['ARTICULO_PRECIO_VENTA']; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Cant. Nuevas: <?php echo $articulo_nuevo; ?>, Cant. Defectuosos: <?php echo $articulo_defectuoso; ?>, Cant. Incompletas: <?php echo $articulo_incompleto; ?>">
<?php echo $desc_producto; ?>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
```

Javascript:

```
 // Código JavaScript en el archivo original
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
// Cargar el datalist mediante AJAX y luego procesar las opciones
cargarDatalist();

// Función para mostrar el tooltip
function showTooltip(element) {
    var tooltip = document.createElement('div');
    tooltip.innerHTML = 'Cant. Nuevas: ' + element.getAttribute('data-cant') + '<br>Cant. Defectuosos: ' + element.getAttribute('data-precio') + '<br>Cant. Incompletas: ' + element.getAttribute('data-precio');
    tooltip.style.position = 'absolute';
    tooltip.style.background = '#f9f9f9';
    tooltip.style.border = '1px solid #a0a0a0';
    tooltip.style.padding = '10px';
    tooltip.style.zIndex = '1000';
    element.parentNode.appendChild(tooltip);
}

// Función para ocultar el tooltip
function hideTooltip(element) {
    var tooltip = element.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
    element.parentNode.removeChild(tooltip);
}

// Agregar eventos a las opciones del datalist
document.addEventListener('mouseover', function (event) {
    if (event.target.tagName === 'OPTION') {
        showTooltip(event.target);
    }
});

document.addEventListener('mouseout', function (event) {
    if (event.target.tagName === 'OPTION') {
        hideTooltip(event.target);
    }
});

// Función para cargar el datalist mediante AJAX
function cargarDatalist() {
    // Realiza una solicitud AJAX para obtener el datalist y agregarlo al DOM
    // Asegúrate de que la respuesta del servidor contenga el datalist adecuado
    // Puedes usar XMLHttpRequest, Fetch API o cualquier otra biblioteca AJAX que prefieras.
}
```

});

Pero nada que me funciona, si alguien sabe como puedo mostrar de forma organizada y presentable al usuario. Debo mostrar la referencia, la descripción. Las cantidades:
Total: 20
Nuevo: 5
Defectuoso: 15
Incompleto: 0

Algo así. Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan ofrecer

Comment: Tu pregunta nada tiene que ver con PHP, según lo que entendí tu problema es de HTML y quizas de JS. Favor colocar un [MCVE] quitando el código que no aporta nada

Comment: Si estás usando Bootstrap, basta con agregar esto a tu `.css`: **`.tooltip-inner { white-space: pre-wrap; }`**. Para más detalles, revisa las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3340802/5587982).

Comment: Lo veo difícil con `<datalist>`, de hecho sus estilos y la forma en la que se presentan son variables entre navegadores, aunque con JS/CSS se le puede dar algo de personalización "forzada". Así que imagina agregarle saltos de línea o tooltips a esos `option` si contrabajo y de manera simulada se puede a los `<select>`. En algún futuro quizá lo estandaricen mejor. Así que la única forma que veo por ahora es que lo dejes como un `<input type="text">` y con JS le des la funcionalidad que te muestre una lista según lo que vayas escribiendo como sugerencias.